# KIE Scanner - 6.1.0.Final - not Loading LATEST kJAR

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

I am working on Drolls 6.1.0.Final. And my LATEST assets are not getting loaded. We have created a kJar 1.0 with 5 rules in KIE-Workbench 6.1.0.Final. We start our application server with KContainer having ReleaseId(gtoup, Artifact , LATEST). Rules are firing. Now add another rule in workbench increment the kJar version 1.1 and perform build and deploy.  After waiting for 5mins fire the rules in application, LATEST Version IS NOT downloaded in m2 local repo and old rules are getting fired. I even tries with setting maven's update policy as interval:1, but in vain.

KIE Scanner is only getting triggered if I manually change the latest version and last updated in  metadata.xml in local m2 repo. In this case KIE Scanner loads the new rules.

Kindly let us know what needs to be done.

**Similar Issue**
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-477

Comment: You might receive more attention if you post this on the Drools user list.

Comment: Thanks laune.  Can u share the url to drools user list

Comment: Your search machines don't work? - The rules-users mailing list has become high volume and it seems natural to split the group into those asking for help with setup, configuration, installation and administration and those who are asking for help with authoring and executing of rules. For this reason rules-users will be split into two groups - drools-setup and drools-usage.  Drools Setup - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-setup
Drools Usage - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage

Answer (score 0):

I know its old post but may be useful for others.
LATEST will not update rule at runtime instead it will load kjar from your local. So try to increase version number or use SNAPSHOT  like 1-SNAPSHOT. When you use version as SNAPSHOT everytime it will check latest kjar.
Also check below settings.xml.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
          <id>uf-playground</id>
          <username>root</username>
          <password>root</password>
          <configuration>
            <wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>
            <httpConfiguration>
              <all>
                <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
              </all>
            </httpConfiguration>
          </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>uf-playground</id>
                    <name>Drools workbench</name>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/kie-drool-6.4/maven2/</url>
                    **<snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>**
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```